# Amzon s3-The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java-8

I am developing desktop app in this I upload object on Amazon S3 for this I get exception-

**software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException) software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException: The specified key does not exist. (Service: S3, Status Code: 404, Request ID: J7QYYDYQFQC31CSC, Extended Request ID: eZXDTDlXlFJ+ZrHL3ip160I5MeUFInbLsNHSgNyH1CmunkLvp+4CVuZxrPGRLlJz1Ot5DmssU0c=)**

My code block is -

> GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
> GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(objectName).build();
> **> ResponseInputStream responese = this.s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);**

when I get response it throws exception. How to resolve this.

Comment: What are your values for `bucketName` and `objectName`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the key / object does not exist.

Comment: This error means the requested object is missing from the bucket. So before using GET or HEAD requests for an object, make sure that the object is created and available in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the AWS SDK for Java to get an object from an Amazon S3 bucket. Your exception message means that you specified a key name (Object) that does not exist.

To help you fix this issue, I will demonstrate a simple use case. Assume you have an object named **book.pdf** in a bucket named **MyBucket**.

To use the Java Amazon S3 API V2 to get the PDF object as a byte[] and then write the PDF to a local file, you use this code:

```
public static void getObjectBytes (S3Client s3, String path ) {

        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key("book.pdf")
                    .bucket("MyBucket")
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file
            File myFile = new File(path );
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
           System.exit(1);
        }
     }
```